# I'm having trouble with the layout in tablet and mobile views on my portfolio and elements aren't displaying properly

Tags: reactjs, debugging

I'm hoping someone can help direct me with troubleshooting for my portfolio page. I'm currently having issues with a few things and I'm not sure why or how to deal with them. Whenever I try to view them in tablet/mobile views on the deployed link the layout is completely different than when I run a live server with npm start.

The first issue about section in mobile and tablet views displays each paragraph in columns and the black background doesn't cover all of the text or the image.

The second issue is the contact page doesn't display the links on mobile even though the text color is set to black and the contact header doesn't show up on the page.

It was made in React. Below will be the deployed link and link to the github.

https://refactored-potato.netlify.app/
https://github.com/GSometimes/refactored-potato

I would really appreciate any help or guidance on sorting this out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first piece of advice is that you have used TOO MUCH CSS, please use only what you really need. You don't need every css property to use on every element.

Your text/paragraphs are showing in column as their parent's display style is set first as inline and then flex. Either don't use it or write `display: block`